# Unit Test Not Working Correctly in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to test a POST function in C# using the Testing Framework that ships with Visual Studio 2013.

The Method I am testing works.  I am able to POST a message and persist it.  However, when I got to run Unit tests, it fails.

The method in question:

```
public class MessageController : ApiController
{
    private MessageContexts db = new MessageContexts();

    // POST api/message
    public HttpResponseMessage PostMessage(Message message)
    {
        if (message is Message)
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.Content = new StringContent("Message Sent!");
            message.MessageSentAt = DateTime.Now;

            db.Messages.Add(message);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.Content = new StringContent("Error!");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

And the test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Post()
{
    //Arrange
    Message message = new Message{MessageFrom = 3, MessageTo=2, MessageContent = "Test Test Test"};
    MessageController controller = new MessageController();

    //Act
    var response = controller.PostMessage(message);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(response);   
}
```

Note: I plan on doing more asserts in my test, but this is just a general idea.  When I run the test, I get an error on the line

```
db.Messages.Add(message);
```

The message states:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is db? Obviously it is null, you need to mock it out in your tests somehow.

Comment: @reggaeguitar I am using MySQL and EntityFramework 6

Comment: Show the code that declares and initializes db. You should use dependency injection to inject it into your class, then you can mock it with a mocking framework such as FakeItEasy

Comment: @reggaeguitar I have added the requested code

Comment: Your problem is that you're newing up your db. You need to ask for it in the constructor of your class. Read up on dependency injection

Comment: You should also only assert one thing per test. That way, if it fails, you know exactly what broke. I recommend Roy Osherove's book The Art of Unit Testing and Depency Injection in .NET by Mark Seemann, they are excellent books that will get you on the right track.

Comment: This is not an answer to your problem, but `if (message is Message)` will always be true, because message is of type Message.  It's impossible for it to not be of type Message.